# Which PDF tool is the easiest to write scripts for?

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser-addons

I'm working on a project where I'm recording the mouse positions when someone is reading a pdf document. I tried Adobe because I heard it has a javascript console, but I had to pay for the professional edition. I tried pdf.js (which reads the pdf and renders it as a canvas in a browser) but it doesn't align characters properly, which defeats the purpose.

So I was wondering, are there any good pdf readers, stand alone applications or browser plug ins, that will let me add scripts onto them?

Comment: Not sure @Ram.  But I suggest you work with Adobe anyway.  The software is ubiquitous and the scripts you write will be found to work for more people on more systems.

Comment: @Jason Gennaro We, eventually, did wind up writing it for Adobe. But there is a lot of red tape to actually make Adobe run the scripts. Just thought I will let you know. Thank you.